# Get Track detail in gracenote API

Tags: gracenote

I am using grace note API to list tracks and albums.
Can anyone please let me know how Can I get track details such as link?
I am getting **track_gnid**
below is the response to `$results = $api->searchTrack("Kings Of Convenience", "Riot On An Empty Street", "Homesick");`

```
[tracks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [track_number] => 1
                            [track_gnid] => 59247313-E198021B46C38679362C35619E93396B
                            [track_title] => Homesick
                            [track_artist_name] => Kings Of Convenience
                            [mood] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [tempo] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )
```

I want to get track link or anything like that

Comment: You should be more specific when you ask questions. Which SDK or library are you using? What are you referring to when you say 'link'? Link to what?

Comment: This is irrelevant to your question, but did you get the developer's account for non-commercial use? I've been contacting them multiple times to get one, but they never replied.